# Getting dates normalized to current year

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a time series in a postgresql / timescale db server and I would like to plot it in grafana so I can easily compare different years.

[image]

At the moment I have two different queries in grafana for the two years, but what I would like to do is to just have one query that extract the year from the timestamp and adjusts the timestamp to be the same date in the current year, eg if I have the following points

```
timestamp           | value
--------------------+-------
2022-02-01 12:00:00 | 4.4
2023-03-02 12:00:00 | 5.7
2021-02-01 12:00:00 | 1.2
```

I would like a query that if run in 2023 would return

```
timestamp           | value | year
--------------------+-------+------
2023-02-01 12:00:00 | 4.4   | 2022 
2023-03-02 12:00:00 | 5.7   | 2023
2023-02-01 12:00:00 | 1.2   | 2021
```

i.e. in "pseudo-SQL" something like

```
select timestamp+year(now())-year(timestamp), value, year(timestamp) 
from datatable where ...
```

is something like this possible in SQL? I am using postgresql 14.

Comment: For best results, define the desired resolution (days?), and how you intend to match leap years to normal years exactly.

Comment: I would suggest just simply removing Feb. 29th, the data loss won't be great and you'll remove any computational overhead associated with adjusting for leap years! It's a legitimate technique in data science as long as you're sure it won't materially affect the end result! If you're analysing data over an entire year, 1/366th data loss doesn't strike me as being a great loss! Also, **NEVER EVER** use [identifiers](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) as table or column (or anything else) names - it's error prone and non-portable.

Comment: As always, could the person who voted down please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible - you can use [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-datetime.html) to truncate your timestamp to the year, subtract that from the original timestamp and then add that to the start-of-year timestamp corresponding to current_timestamp.

This is likely to give you dangerous results because years are not the same lengths - for large-scale patterns this is probably fine, but it will still be deceptive to assign data to the present year. In particular, if the current year is not a leap year and you try adding a timestamp from the end of a leap year, you will report a date in the next year (however this should still display after other dates in this year on the graph). You should instead just plot the interval from start-of-year to timestamp (without adding it to your current start-of-year timestamp).

I.e. the output can be `timestamp - date_trunc('year', timestamp)` - **you probably don't need to** add `date_trunc('year', current_timestamp)`.

Answer (score 1):

[`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) seems like the right tool. (Functional equivalent: `date_part()`.)
Assuming the resolution of your plot is *days*:

```
SELECT extract('doy'  FROM ts)::int AS day_of_year
     , extract('year' FROM ts)::int AS year
     , value
FROM   datatable
WHERE  ...
```

Feb 28 will always be day 59.
Mar 01 is day 60 in normal years, but day 61 in leap years. Etc.

The cast to `integer` is optional. We just don't need `numeric` output for this.

Be aware that `timestamptz` values are cast to `timestamp` based on your current `timezone` setting. If the input is `timestamptz` I suggest to use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct to get immutable results. Basics:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Aside: I'd avoid using basic type names like "timestamp" as identifier. Too error-prone.